# Replacing string with variables stored in an array

Tags: php

OK so i'm unsure with my syntax on this one, I do think the logic is self explanatory but I'm unsure if preg_replace will work or whether a loop is needed to get an end result.

```
$string = $randomizer->fecthRandomPhrase($cfg['seo']['meta']['descriptions']['single'], 3, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Returns a string  like this

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,[address1], [address2], [postcode].  consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris id dui sem, eget laoreet tellus. Vivamus lacinia vestibulum odio a lobortis - [region]

I then search the string for the parts I want to change;

```
$find = array('[address1]','[address2]','[postcode]','[region]');
```

I then pull information stored in these variables and place them in an array;

```
$replace = array($ADDRESS1,$ADDRESS2,$POSTCODE,$region);
```

The before returning the phrase I apply a preg_replace to swap over the info I have stored

```
$phrase = preg_replace($find,$replace,$string);
```

Do I need to loop through the array $replace to allow the reading of each variable and for the replace to work or am I using the wrong function entirely?

Comment: Thanks for tidying that up Antony, I knew there would be a spelling mistake or missing code block somehow. (flux on screen makes it harder to see the grey boxes lol)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace) can take arrays as its first two parameters, you might want to consider that instead. Otherwise, you'd need to form a proper regex for `$find` in order to only invoke `preg_replace()` once, which you currently are not doing.

Usage:

```
$phrase = str_replace( $find, $replace, $string);
```

Now `$phrase` shoud contain your desired output.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for that i'll make sure to use str_replace when passing arrays this did the trick. Thanks nickb

Answer (score 2):

use PHP's [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function like this

```
str_replace(array($your_replacement_array), array($your_replace_array), $string);
```

Hence what you want is this

```
str_replace(array('[address1]','[address2]','[postcode]',['region']), array($ADDRESS1,$ADDRESS2,$POSTCODE,$region), $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

`strtr` is also useful.

On the following situation, only `strtr` works exptectedly.

```
$text = 'SonyEricsson is based in British, but Sony is based in Japan';
```

## str_replace

code:

```
$search  = array(
    'SonyEricsson',
    'Sony',
);
$replace = array(
    '<a href="http://www.SonyEricsson.com">SonyEricsson</a>',
    '<a href="http://www.Sony.com">Sony</a>',
);
echo str_replace($search,$replace,$text);
```

result:

```
<a href="http://www.<a href="http://www.Sony.com">Sony</a>Ericsson.com"><a href="http://www.Sony.com">Sony</a>Ericsson</a> is based in British, but <a href="http://www.Sony.com">Sony</a> is based in Japan
```

## strtr

code:

```
$replace_pairs = array(
    'SonyEricsson' => '<a href="http://www.SonyEricsson.com">SonyEricsson</a>',
    'Sony'         => '<a href="http://www.Sony.com">Sony</a>',
);
echo strtr($text,$replace_pairs);
```

result:

```
<a href="http://www.SonyeEricsson.com">SonyEricsson</a> is based in British, but <a href="http://www.Sony.com">Sony</a> is based in Japan
```

Comment: I'll try to work this method with my next task as the next group of variables I need to replace are 3d arrays, I'm needing to replace more than once piece of information about a building such as the case with my example in the question I assume it would be easier to find all of the text I need to replace rather than splitting it up into multiple variables?

Comment: Are you meaning that sending paired arguments like `strtr` is superior to sending splitted arguments like `str_replace`?